# MySQL join 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.
Table 1 Assets has asset_id and asset_type_id
Table 2 Asset Types has asset_type_id and asset_type_name
Table 3 Transactions has asset_id and timestamp

I am trying to get a list of every asset with its name and most recent log entry if it exists

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_2.name
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.type_id = table_2.id
```

gives me the list of assets with names.

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_2.name, MAX(table_3.timestamp) as last
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.arcade_machine_id = table_2.id
LEFT JOIN transaction_log ON table_1.id = table_3.asset_id
```

gives me only the first asset with name and log entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix normal column selects with aggregation selects like MAX(). Group your data and the aggregation functions will apply to each group:

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_2.name, MAX(table_3.timestamp) as last
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.arcade_machine_id = table_2.id
LEFT JOIN transaction_log ON table_1.id = table_3.asset_id 
GROUP BY table_1.id, table_2.name
```